# How to find checkout_submit_all_after event

Tags: checkout, event-observer, magento-1, sales-order

Is there any way  to find how much or who is using/listing specific core event ?

I want to find,On my Magento which extensions are using event "**checkout_submit_all_after**" .

Please help me for this..

Answer (score 0):

You can find the "checkout_submit_all_after" string/event by using grep command in your instances.

> grep -i -n -r "checkout_submit_all_after" /var/www/mymagentoinstance/

Most possible way is you can find it in config.xml in the modules(custom/core)

Grep command will give you the list of files found the string, then you able to identify the use of the event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Other way ? I have ftp details only so I need to create a script.

Comment: You can download custom modules(app/code/vendor/module) from ftp and grep the string accordingly.

Comment: Hi..Its not helpful to me..because there are no. of extensions on store .So it is not possible to download extension and check . :(

Comment: Then where you want to search the string ?